# How to install python 2.5.4?

Tags: 12.10, python, software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop, now i want to use Python 2.5.4 for educational purpose. Can any one help me with step by step instructions... I also need IDLE for 2.5.4.

Comment: 2.5.4? Why? "Python 2.5.4 has been replaced by a newer bugfix release of Python" Should that not be 2.5.6 according to: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.4/

Comment: Please create a new question for idle. AU works best with 1 question and 1 valid answer.

Answer (score 12):

I use https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes for all the old python versions.

It seems maintained and new versions are also added.

simply do the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.5
```

Comment: Excellent and easier than mine so +1 ;)

Comment: This and virtualenv's has saved me enourmous ammounts of hassle ;)

Comment: This method does install 2.5.6 btw. I got distracted by the question asking for 2.5.4...

Answer (score 6):

This will install 2.5.4 from **source**:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc
cd Downloads
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.4/Python-2.5.4.tgz
tar -xvzf Python-2.5.4.tgz
cd Python-2.5.4
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.5
make
make test
sudo checkinstall --pkgname python2.5 --provides python2.5
```

**NOTE:** if compiling was halted with error from `Modules/getbuildinfo.o`  and `Modules/getbuildinfo.c`  ---> redo the configure command like this `SVNVERSION=not-found ./configure --prefix=[your/path/preference]`

If you want to replace your standard python:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python2.5/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.5 </pre>
```

You can use this version by issuing `python2.5` instead of `python`.

Comment: Can you explain what the `checkinstall` command does? Seems like `make install` is the normal thing to do.

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall It IS `make install` + extras.

Comment: On modern systems, this produces a Python unable to run hashlib (if any, on many system the build will just crash). Here is my minimal fork of Python 2.5 that builds in 2016 on debian sid: https://github.com/phihag/python2.5 .